# How to upload multiple images to a server into a Django application?

Tags: php, javascript, django, angularjs, tastypie

I'm currently working on a Django application using AngularJS for the frontend part.
I want for the moment to upload some images on the server and get as callback a list with the paths of the uploaded files. I want to send afterwards to the API (I am using Tastypie framework) as a POST request the callback and insert it into the database in a specific field. My issue is that I don't know how to approach the images upload (I should use PHP?) part and most important how to receive the callback? I hope that I explain clear enough. :D

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for uploading files in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

HTML only allows to upload one file per upload-controller. To upload multiple files either the user can create a zip file (or similar), upload that and on the server side you extract it into multiple files. Or you have to use a flash component. There are lots of these available, for example http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/